# using cell as reference in query function

Tags: google-sheets

First off, apologies if i'm posting this in the wrong place, been a long time since i've been here. I'm attempting to reference a cell while using the query function, but keep getting an error. Is it possible to do this, if so how?

[this is my attempt to reference cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV4fL.png)

[Seems to work when using a constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAUAO.png)

Answer (score 0):

actually, just realized there was a issue with the example i found. Turns out the double quotes are incorrect.

[see correction below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFoKZ.png)